# how to make a textfield numeric by default in lwuit?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

i tried to make a application which takes the numeric value default.
i have done coding like this

```
public void startApp(){
Display.init(this);
TextField amt=new TextField();
Form form=new Form(Test);
form.addComponent(amt);
amt.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);
form.show(); 

}
```

When i setConstraint to numeric. it only accepts numeric value but i need to press the hash key and chage the key entry style to numeric. so how can i make the text field which should only be able to take numeric input by default. 
thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInputModeOrder(...);`. See the following sample code,

```
TextField txtf = new TextField();
txtf.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);
txtf.setInputModeOrder(new String[] {"123"});
form.addComponent(txtf);
```